# TestContainers and LocalStack S3: Invalid S3 URI: hostname does not appear to be a valid S3 endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, testcontainers, localstack

I am trying to extract `AWS` Object URL via the following code:

```
s3AsyncClient.utilities()
                .getUrl(r -> r.region(awsRegion).bucket(bucketName).key(key));
```

For Integration tests where I am using `TestContainers` and `LocalStack` `S3`, the returned URL looks like this:

```
        http://127.0.0.1:51435/my-bucket/games/123.json
```

The URL looks good to me, but when I try to transform `URL` to `S3Uri`:

```
        S3Uri s3Uri = s3AsyncClient.utilities().parseUri(url.toURI());
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid S3 URI: hostname does not appear to be a valid S3 endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:51435/my-bucket/games/123.json
```

Seems that the aws parser doesn't accept `127.0.0.1` as a valid `s3` endpoint, but what should I do?
Not sure that I can force the AWS parser to accept `127.0.0.1` as a valid host, but maybe it is possible somehow to configure `LocalStack` `S3` to return an acceptable hostname instead of an IP address?

Current `Localstack` `S3` configuration see below:

```
    private static final LocalStackContainer LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER = new LocalStackContainer(LOCAL_STACK_IMAGE)
            .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3);

    static {
        LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void s3Properties(final DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("ssp.s3.region", LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER::getRegion);
        registry.add("ssp.s3.endpoint", () -> LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3));
    }
```

Comment: What is s3AsyncClient and where does it come from?  I suspect you're using an unsupported version of the AWS S3 SDK.

Comment: @lane.maxwell It comes from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3/2.23.3

Comment: @lane.maxwell, btw,         AmazonS3URI uri = new AmazonS3URI("http://127.0.0.1:51435/my-bucket/games/123.json"); that belongs to java sdk v1 also throws exactly the same exception.

Comment: It looks like you've stumbled on a pseudo bug in LocalStack.  I say pseudo because while this does manifest itself in S3 based on the LocalStack configuration, it's only in the utilities class and doesn't prevent the S3Client or AsyncS3Client from functioning normally.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I guess, you are right, I was able successfully to upload a file to the s3 bucket and successfully received the uploaded file URL, but I wasn't able to download the file because the AWS parser rejected the URL as invalid.

Comment: Hum, it shouldn't prevent you from being able to perform any of the operations.  I was able to create a bucket, upload an object, and retrieve it with both the S3Client and the AsyncS3Client simply by using the `getObject` methods of each.  I'll throw an answer on here that shows the test, maybe you get something useful from it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your issue, but I believe it will create a workaround.  In order to solve the issue that you're facing, AWS will have to modify their parser to allow for this (you can't even use localhost because the AWS parser requires the URL to contain `s3`).

Here is a test that creates a bucket, puts an object, and then gets the object for both the `S3Client` and the `AsyncS3Client`.

```
@Test
public void testS3ClientsAgainstLocalStack() {
    String s3Bucket = "s3bucket";
    String asyncS3Bucket = "async-s3bucket";
    LocalStackContainer localStackContainer = new LocalStackContainer
            (DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack"))
            .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3);
    localStackContainer.start();

    S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(localStackContainer.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3))
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    localStackContainer.getAccessKey(), localStackContainer.getSecretKey()
            )))
            .region(Region.of(localStackContainer.getRegion()))
            .build();

    S3Client s3Client = S3Client
            .builder()
            .endpointOverride(localStackContainer.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3))
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    localStackContainer.getAccessKey(), localStackContainer.getSecretKey()
            )))
            .region(Region.of(localStackContainer.getRegion()))
            .build();

    s3Client.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest.builder().bucket(s3Bucket).build());
    s3AsyncClient.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest.builder().bucket(asyncS3Bucket).build());

    ListBucketsResponse s3ListBucketsResponse = s3Client.listBuckets();
    CompletableFuture<ListBucketsResponse> asyncS3ListBucketsResponse = s3AsyncClient.listBuckets();

    PutObjectRequest s3PutObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Bucket)
            .key("s3File")
            .build();

    PutObjectRequest asyncS3PutObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(asyncS3Bucket)
            .key("asyncS3File")
            .build();

    PutObjectResponse putObjectResponse = s3Client.putObject(s3PutObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes("Just Some Content".getBytes()));
    CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> putObjectResponseCompletableFuture = s3AsyncClient.putObject(s3PutObjectRequest, AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes("Just Some Content".getBytes()));

    GetObjectRequest s3GetObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Bucket)
            .key("s3File")
            .build();

    GetObjectRequest asyncS3GetObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Bucket)
            .key("asyncS3File")
            .build();

    ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3ClientGetObjectResponse = s3Client.getObject(s3GetObjectRequest);
    CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>> asyncS3ClientGetObjectResponse = s3AsyncClient.getObject(asyncS3GetObjectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream());
}
```

Comment: thank you for the samples, the problem appears when you need to implement the following method:

public String download(final Url resourceUrl){...}